# Does this contradict contradict identity theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

based on this Identity theorem: http://planetmath.org/IdentityTheorem
Let $\Omega$ be a open connected subset of $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e., a domain). If f and g are analytic on $\Omega$ and ${z\inΩ:f(z)=g(z)}$ has an accumulation point in $\Omega$, then $f≡g$ on $\Omega$.

now let $R(z) = \frac{(z-2) \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(z-3) \left(z-\frac{1}{3}\right)}$, we can verify that $R(z)$ is Real on $|z|=1$ . then  by  the identity theorem,$R(z)$ is Real on the whole $\mathcal{C}$. but this is NOT true. please correct me ,thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing "$f$ is real on $E$, hence $f$ is real everywhere" with "$f(z)=g(z)$ on $E$, hence $f(z)=g(z)$ everywhere". Note that $f(z) = z$ is real on the real-axis and of course is not real everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The unit circle is not an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: but , [the Identity theorem](http://planetmath.org/IdentityTheorem) seem to not require it 's an open  connected subset. maybe that definition is wrong?

Comment: The first sentence is "Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$"...

Comment: @BenjaminPeterson  In his set-up the domain is $\mathbb {C}\setminus \{1/3,3\},$ a connected open set. So that's not where the problem is. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think i make a mistake in the very beginning. Provided $R(z)$ is analytic. then $\overline{R(z)}$ is generally **NOT** analytic.

Now $R(z)=\frac{(z-2) \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(z-3) \left(z-\frac{1}{3}\right)}$ want to be Real, then $f(z)=R(z) - \overline{R(z)}$ should be identically $0$.

Even $f(z) = 0$ on $|z| = 1$, but $f(z)$ is **NOT** analytic.  then the  Identity theorem is **NOT** applicable. so $f(z)$ can **NOT** be identically $0$ on $\mathcal{C}$. there is **NO** contradiction.

At last, i want give my thanks to **Benjamin Peterson** and **zhw**. your answers is very important clues for me.